# Sending e-mail in asp with usings

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, email

I have an `email form` on my website which is working great. The only thing I want to do is add `usings` for better coding, what is the best way to do this? The code I use is the following:

```
            try
            {
            //create message
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
            msg.Subject = string.Format("Van: " + txtName.Text + " | Email: " + txtFrom.Text + " | Onderwerp: " + txtSubject.Text);
            msg.Body = txtBericht.Text;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("");
            smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailaddress", "pass");

                smtp.Send(msg);
                ClearTextboxes();
                lblError.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblError.Text = "Het verzenden van uw e-mail is gelukt!";
            }
            catch
            {
                lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblError.Text = "Er ging iets mis met het versturen van de email."; 
            }
```

How can I use `usings` on this code?
And is it safe to use fill in my emailaddress and password when I'm uploading my website, or should I use another method?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I changed my code to the following:

```
  try
            {
            //create message
                using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
                {

                     //create message
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
            msg.Subject = string.Format("Van: " + txtName.Text + " | Email: " + txtFrom.Text + " | Onderwerp: " + txtSubject.Text);
            msg.Body = txtBericht.Text;

                    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailadress", "pass");

                        smtp.Send(msg);
                    }
                    ClearTextboxes();
                    lblError.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblError.Text = "Het verzenden van uw e-mail is gelukt!";
                }          
            }
            catch
            {
                lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblError.Text = "Er ging iets mis met het versturen van de email."; 
            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Dispose of `SmtpClient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never put authentication information in your code.  Put it in your web.config instead and reference it where you need it.  That also saves you the trouble of hunting down everywhere you used it if you change your password.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misunderstanding this, this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Actually it does half and the answer by @Nikita does also answer half of my question.

Comment: Richard, would it still be better to put the smtp settings into .config if I use Windows Authentication and the only think I specify if the Host? It is only used in one page only once.

Comment: I put any authentication information, or any information that might change in the future related to the app functionality in the web.config.  It's an easy place to manage and change the information.  Putting any identifying information in the code itself can cause issues in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the web.config for setting up the host, username and password. Example.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="name@domain.com">
            <network host="smtp.mail.com" 
                     userName="name@domain.com" 
                     password="blog.dotnetclr.com" port="25"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Code Example:

```
Public Sub SendEmail([to] As String, subject As String, body As String)
    Dim mailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    mailMessage.[To].Add([to])
    mailMessage.Subject = subject
    mailMessage.Body = body

    Dim smtpClient = New SmtpClient()
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = True
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
End Sub
```

Comment: The first snippet of web.config helped me a lot, I voted to much today, so I will upvote you tommorrow first work of my day:)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx

```
using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
{
    //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use using for both MailMessage and SMTP Client objects

```
           //create message
           using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(""))
           using( MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
           {

                // Your code

           }
```

Comment: Should I do that for both, is that better coding?

Comment: What is the value of putting the `MailMessage` in a `using` statement? The `SmtpClient` uses resources that you want to dispose of but does the same hold true for `MailMessage`?

Comment: I think use of 'using' for SmtpClient is much more sensible than using it for MailMessage as GC will eventually cleanup but we are trying to have deterministic finalization for both.. Hope it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

```
    using(SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()){
        //smtp options here
        using(MailMessage msg = new MailMessage()){
            //mail options here
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
    }
```